# Getting HTTP ERROR: 404 for Jenkins after forwarding port with public IP

Tags: jenkins, automation, jetty, portforwarding, cicd

I have Jenkins locally running on port 8081 on a linux machine that is setup in office .
I have a public IP that I am trying to use to make Jenkins publicly available.
I have entered the public IP with port in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins
URL like: `http://182.156.xxx.xx:8081/`

Now if I direct to `http://182.156.xxx.xx:8081/` , it gives me HTTP 404 error(screenshot attached).

Note: I have setup the Jenkins in Ubuntu with below commands:

1. wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
2. sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > 
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install jenkins

etc/default/jenkins file:

```
# defaults for Jenkins automation server

# pulled in from the init script; makes things easier.
NAME=jenkins

# arguments to pass to java

# Allow graphs etc. to work even when an X server is present
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

#JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"

# make jenkins listen on IPv4 address
#JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid

# user and group to be invoked as (default to jenkins)
JENKINS_USER=$NAME
JENKINS_GROUP=$NAME

# location of the jenkins war file
JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/$NAME/$NAME.war

# jenkins home location
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/$NAME

# set this to false if you don't want Jenkins to run by itself
# in this set up, you are expected to provide a servlet container
# to host jenkins.
RUN_STANDALONE=true

# log location.  this may be a syslog facility.priority
JENKINS_LOG=/var/log/$NAME/$NAME.log
#JENKINS_LOG=daemon.info

# Whether to enable web access logging or not.
# Set to "yes" to enable logging to /var/log/$NAME/access_log
JENKINS_ENABLE_ACCESS_LOG="no"

# OS LIMITS SETUP
#   comment this out to observe /etc/security/limits.conf
#   this is on by default because http://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/2fb288474e980d0e7ff9c4a3b768874835a3e92e
#   reported that Ubuntu's PAM configuration doesn't include pam_limits.so, and as a result the # of file
#   descriptors are forced to 1024 regardless of /etc/security/limits.conf
MAXOPENFILES=8192

# set the umask to control permission bits of files that Jenkins creates.
#   027 makes files read-only for group and inaccessible for others, which some security sensitive users
#   might consider benefitial, especially if Jenkins runs in a box that's used for multiple purposes.
#   Beware that 027 permission would interfere with sudo scripts that run on the master (JENKINS-25065.)
#
#   Note also that the particularly sensitive part of $JENKINS_HOME (such as credentials) are always
#   written without 'others' access. So the umask values only affect job configuration, build records,
#   that sort of things.
#
#   If commented out, the value from the OS is inherited,  which is normally 022 (as of Ubuntu 12.04,
#   by default umask comes from pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs

# UMASK=027

# port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
HTTP_PORT=8081


# servlet context, important if you want to use apache proxying
PREFIX=/$NAME

# arguments to pass to jenkins.
# --javahome=$JAVA_HOME
# --httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST (default 0.0.0.0)
# --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT (default 8080; disable with -1)
# --httpsPort=$HTTP_PORT
# --argumentsRealm.passwd.$ADMIN_USER=[password]
# --argumentsRealm.roles.$ADMIN_USER=admin
# --webroot=~/.jenkins/war
# --prefix=$PREFIX

JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
```

In this jenkins file, I have only changed the HTTP PORT from 8080 to 8081. As on port 8080, the jenkins is already running with the same public IP.

Jenkins version : 2.289.2
Java version : 8
Ubuntu version : 20.04

[jenkins_error_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db040.png)

Comment: That is just a generic jetty 404 response.  Your request is not even hitting the `jenkins.war`.  Please edit your question and copy/paste your Jenkins startup procedure (are you using jetty-home/jetty-base, are you using winstone built into the jenkins.war, etc) and any command line (with arguments) you are using.

Comment: Hey @JoakimErdfelt .. thanks for your response. I have updated the question above.

Comment: Thanks, that's a step in the right direction, but it doesn't tell us anything about your current configuration.  For example, what is your `/etc/default/jenkins` contents? What else (startup related) have you changed?  What version of Jenkins are you running? What version of Ubuntu are you running? What version of Java are you running? (simply following your directions with ubuntu 12.04 results in no issues.  so we need more information)

Comment: Apologies @JoakimErdfelt .. I have updated the description above. Hope this will help.

Comment: Hey @JoakimErdfelt .. you got any clue to resolve this?